# Magento resize image

Tags: php, magento

I am using the below code to display product images by their label:

```
$productId = $this->getProduct_id(); 
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);


src="<?php echo $_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'mylabel')->getUrl(); ?>"
```

How can I resize the image?

Comment: $_image->resize(50, 50);

Answer (score 1):

// Image name

$image = "";

```
    // actual image path
```

//$imageUrl = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). DS .'test'. DS .$image;

in your case image url is

```
$imageUrl="<?php echo $_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'mylabel')->getUrl(); ?>"


    // Give resized image path to be saved
    // here, the resized image will save in media/test/resized folder
```

$imageResized = Mage::getBaseDir('media'). DS .'test'. DS .'resized'. DS .$image;

```
    // image will resize only if the image file exists and the resized image file doesn't exist



 if (!file_exists($imageResized) && file_exists($imageUrl))
    {
        $imageObj = new Varien_Image($imageUrl);
        $imageObj->constrainOnly(TRUE);
        $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);
        $imageObj->keepFrame(FALSE);
        $imageObj->resize(300, null);
        $imageObj->save($imageResized);
    }
```

hope this will help you